# How to route to a page on a server using an onclick button?

Tags: javascript, html, server, intel, intel-galileo

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="on()">Force ON </button>


<script type="text/javascript">
function on(){req.url="/ledOn";}
</script>
```

This is my HTML button and i just need to route make it route to "ledOn" page in server.js file in order to perform some operations.
and this is the server.js file code.

```
var http = require('http');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var fs = require('fs');
var system = require('child_process').exec;
//var mraa = require('mraa');

var ledstatus = "off";
//var pin_2 = new mraa.Gpio(2);
//pin_2.dir(mraa.DIR_OUT);

http.createServer(function(req,res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});


  fs.readFile('index.html', 'utf-8', function(err, content) {
    if (err) {
      res.end('error occurred');
      return;
    }

    var temp = 'some temp';  


        console.log("Request: " + req.url);

        if(req.url === "/ledOn") {
            //pin.write(0);
                ledstatus = "on";
            console.log("pin 7 on");
        }
        if(req.url === "/ledOff") {
            //pin.write(1);
                ledstatus = "off";
            console.log("pin 7 off");
        }

    var renderedHtml = ejs.render(content, {temp: temp, ledstatus:ledstatus});  
    res.end(renderedHtml);
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

** i wanna add more buttons with more routes to my html page to use it controlling my galileo board, so any help would be appreciated **

Comment: What is the specific problem or question?

Comment: @charlietfl I just wanna when to click the button on the HTML page it will route to the page in server.js then this action will affect the if statement to execute it's tasks

Comment: Why can't you use `<a>` tags? Still not clear what the specific problem is. You need to do a better job of outlining your problem